# How would I use Android storage access framework for ttf font files

Tags: android

I'm writing a flash card program for Japanese vocabulary that uses multiple fonts. I have the files in the assets directory but I'd like to move them to external memory.  Since these aren't typical media files how do I access them using the storage access framework?  I know how to access individual files but I want to access a directory containing ttf font files.

Answer (score 0):

You can [request access to a directory with SAF](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory) by doing `startActivityForResult` with intent with action [`Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).

In `onActivityResult` you will get intent which `intent.getData()` contains uri for the user selected directory. You can store it somewhere and use it to create [`DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile) with [`DocumentFile#fromTreeUri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#fromTreeUri(android.content.Context,android.net.Uri)) that you can finally use to access individual files.

You probably want to [persist read/write permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions) for the directory so that you can still access it after device restart by doing this:

```
final int takeFlags = intent.getFlags()
            & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
// Check for the freshest data.
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
```

But even with persisted permissions you might lose access to the directory, so be ready to re-request access again.

On last note: you can use [`ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree) contract instead of `startActivityForResult`.